# Is there a way to access to a twitter user's following stream programmatically?

Tags: api, twitter

Months ago, Twitter added a new feature to enable us to see the following stream of a specific user. (see TechCrunch news - [Now You Can See Twitter The Way I See Twitter](https://techcrunch.com/2011/05/26/now-you-can-see-twitter-the-way-i-see-twitter/)).

I cannot find the official api for such data and wandering if such data can be obtained programmatically.

Comment: I have the same question? btw, did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is the first one here: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline

Comment: is that actually the Twitter's REST api?